# Validate form submission against html5 form markup on the server-side?

Tags: html, forms, node.js

Given html5 form markup, and a form-encoded post body, is there a simple way to validate the form? I think it would be cool to reuse html5 form markup itself as the authoritative source of validation rules.

So basically, on the client-side, the browser would validate against the form, and then on the server-side, the server would load the same form, and validate the post body against it again.

I'm most interested in node.js, but any server-side language/framework that makes this easy would be of interest. I thought of using zombie.js, but it does not currently support html5 form constraint validation.

Comment: Did you look into Phantomjs? it supports HTML5

Comment: you wouldn't use the full html5 validation. all you need to do is locally fetch the referrer, parse it as HTML, and compare the existence of require(s) and validating the pattern attribs against the data using new RegExp(attr) upon each of the submitted data fields that has a name attrib in the html.